# How to run bat file for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, cmd

I ma trying to run windows batch file to add postgresql tables.
Is it possible to make this script that i dont need to press enter when cmd box apperas ?

```
@echooff
echo "Test for Passing Params to PGSQL"
SET server=localhost
SET /P server="Server [%server%]: "

SET database=HoldemManager2_1
SET /P database="Database [%database%]: "

SET port=5432
SET /P port="Port [%port%]: "

SET username=postgres
SET /P username="Username [%username%]: "
SET /P bunos="Enter multiple constraint values for IN clause [%constraints%]: "
ECHO you typed %constraints%

PAUSE
REM pause
"C:\postgreSQL\bin\psql.exe" -h %server% -U %username% -d %database% -p %port% -e -v v1=%constraints% -f test.sql
```

Comment: You have to type a lot more than `enter` when the cmd window opens.  Edit your question and clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You script is prompting the user to give the connexion parameter, so it is normal that you have to  validate each parameter asked. And Also you have a `PAUSE` command.